# Infinite horizontal UIScrollView with UIButtons

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton, uilabel

here is what I do at the moment.

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(56, 205, 400, 3000)];
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 3.0f,scrollView.frame.size.height * 3.0f);
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0f;

UIView *zoomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)];
zoomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < 100; index++)
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake((scrollView.frame.size.width / 2.0f) - 50.0f, 10.0f + (50.0f * (CGFloat)index), 100.0f, 30.0f);
    button.tag = index;
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %ld", ((long)index + 1)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [zoomView addSubview:button];
}

[scrollView addSubview:zoomView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

The problem is. It's not inifinite. I would like the number 101 to be the number 1, hope you understand. And how could i create them dynamically, with a webservice telling me how much button i will have, what background i should apply to each button, and what text to put under the button. Also the code above is scrolling vertically, but at the end it would be a non zooming horizontal scrolllview. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to scroll your UIScrollview till the zoomView frame size ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set content size of your scrollview

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(56, 205, 400, 320)]; // it is for iphone. set it's resolution if you want to set it for ipad
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 3.0f,scrollView.frame.size.height * 3.0f);
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0f;

UIView *zoomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)];
zoomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < 100; index++)
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake((scrollView.frame.size.width / 2.0f) - 50.0f, 10.0f + (50.0f * (CGFloat)index), 100.0f, 30.0f);
    button.tag = index;
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %ld", ((long)index + 1)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [zoomView addSubview:button];
}

[scrollView addSubview:zoomView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

scrollView.contentSize= CGSizeMake((zoomView.frame.size.width) , zoomView.frame.size.height);
```

set it after your zoom view has been added into scrollView.
I hope it helps you to understand.